# why no sound after I add MediaElement Source to the music? Web Audio API

Tags: html, visualization, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the Web Audio API as I'm looking to make some visualizations based on the music that's playing. However all examples I have found, it's like the audio is muted. It plays the file but there's no sound.

I know that it entails CORS, and I tried to fix by adding "audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'". But it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

This is the link to codepen: http://codepen.io/lianliu/pen/xwPXvO/?editors=101

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var audio = new Audio("http://w-labs.at/experiments/audioviz/GYAKO.mp3");
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
//var audioElement = document.getElementById('myAudio');
var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
// Bind our analyser to the media element source.
audioSrc.connect(analyser);
audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
audio.play();
audio.volume = 0.5;

//var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(200);

var svgHeight = '300';
var svgWidth = '1200';
var barPadding = '1';

function createSvg(parent, height, width) {
    return d3.select(parent).append('svg').attr('height', height).attr('width', width);
}

var svg = createSvg('body', svgHeight, svgWidth);

// Create our initial D3 chart.
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(frequencyData)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return i * (svgWidth / frequencyData.length);
    })
    .attr('width', svgWidth / frequencyData.length - barPadding);

// Continuously loop and update chart with frequency data.
function renderChart() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderChart);

    // Copy frequency data to frequencyData array.
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

    // Update d3 chart with new data.
    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(frequencyData)
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return svgHeight - d;
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return 'rgb(0, 0, ' + d + ')';
        });
}

// Run the loop
renderChart();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that it entails CORS, and I tried to fix by adding
>   "audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'". But it doesn't work.

You're on the right track. You need to make sure your server serve the mp3 with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set. Set it to the specific domain you're making the request from, or to "*" to access it from anywhere.

How you set the header depends on the server software you're running. Here's a list of different approaches: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

**Edit:**

Try changing the URL to a mp3 that is served with the header set, like

```
http://chrome-jam-static.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/sounds/soundlogo_jam.mp3
```

and you'll see that your code works just fine.

Comment: Thank you! You save my day!

Comment: No problem, @LianLiu! Feel free to mark this answer as correct if it helped you out. :)

Comment: @OskarEriksson I am too facing a similar problem. How can I use local files with the pen in the question?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I think it'd be best if you post a new question with what you've done so far and I'm sure I or someone else will be able to help you out! Tag it web-audio and there's a bunch of clever people that are happy to help!

Comment: @OskarEriksson You seem to be quite familiar about all this web audio stuff..  I am a noob when it comes to this. I will think about posting a new question but it would be very nice if you could help :)